# node.js fnoc module gives error -- probably something simple

Tags: json, node.js, require, node-modules

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I can't get [node-fnoc](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fnoc) to work.  I have a directory with a simple package.json in it, I have a /config/ directory in that directory with a simple JSON file in it.  And, I'm basically just trying to do what they have in their example.

```
var fnoc = require('fnoc');

fnoc(function(err, configs){    
  console.log(configs); 
});
```

and this is what I'm getting:

```
fnoc(function(err, configs){
^
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/backups/readconfig.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The document on github is for version 0.2.2**

You need to install fnoc@0.2.2

```
npm install fnoc@0.2.2
```

**Run your js**

```
node your.js
```

**Output:**

```
{ package:
   { name: 'asdf',
      dependencies:
      { express: '*',
        jade: '*',
```

---

Version is in the changelog file:

https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fnoc/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thank you!

Glad to know it wasn't something stupid I was doing.  Would you mind walking me through how you figured that out?

Comment: sometime, code is easier to understand than document, so goto 'node_modules/fnoc', read the code.